# How to disable previous month in Fullcalendar io?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

How to disable the previous button when the previous month is less than the current month.
For example, this month is March, therefore navigation previous month button must be disable.

I have read the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs) but until now this issue has not been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is the [validRange](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/validRange) option. This allows you to set limits on where the user can navigate to, and where events can be placed.

There's an example in that documentation of how you can prevent the user navigating before the current date - you need to make use of the version of the option which provides a callback function, into which fullCalendar will pass the current date. Simply specify the current date as the `start` of the valid range. If you don't specify an `end` date, then there will be no future limit on the dates the user can navigate to; it will only restrict dates in the past.

```
validRange: function(nowDate) {
  return {
    start: nowDate
  };
},
```

Live demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/yLPQYxr